# Writing Dockerfile for Dockerhub Automated builds

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am new to Docker, so am struggling with a very basic problem.

I have a maven project. In the local environment, all I do to run the project is:

```
mvn clean package jetty:run
```

I am now trying to package this for Automated dockerhub build linked to a github repo. Here are the steps I have taken:

1. Created a Dockerfile as below and added it to the base folder
2. Commit the code to github
3. Created and linked an Autobuild repo in dockerhub to the Github repo.
4. Make necessary changes to point to the specific branch and Dockerfile

When I commit a change, I can see it triggers a build and the build is successful. However, when I run the docker image, it comes back with the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Container command 'mvn clean package jetty:run' not found or does not exist..
```

Here is the folder structure:

```
/Dockerfile
/pom.xml
/src/<folders that contain the code>
```

Here is what I have in the Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.3.9-jdk-8
CMD ["mvn clean package jetty:run"]
```

I think I am missing out on fetching a copy of the code into the container. But what is the best way of doing it? I tried the `COPY` command but I was not able to make it work.

Please help.

Comment: Try this Dockerfile https://github.com/carlossg/docker-maven/blob/b022df671b603a9100ed9e75803ae32f753826a4/jdk-8/onbuild/Dockerfile but delete the `ONBUILD` part.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem here is, that "mvn" is the command and "clean", "package" and "jetty:run" are its parameters. Shells like bash seperate them automatically. Docker does not.

CMD ["mvn clean package jetty:run"] lets docker search for a file with a name like "/usr/bin/mvn clean package jetty:run" which of course does not exist.

A correct form is:

```
CMD ["executable","param1","param2"]
```

In your case:

```
CMD ["/usr/bin/mvn", "clean", "package", "jetty:run"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The [maven Dockerfile](https://github.com/carlossg/docker-maven/blob/993474f006a59f487ef795864fab6115f9b1b8b5/jdk-9/onbuild/Dockerfile) already includes the copy directive, activated when you `docker build` your image (with the [`ONBUILD` directive](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#onbuild)).
It is based on a [maven image](https://github.com/carlossg/docker-maven/blob/40cbcd2edc2719c64062af39baac6ae38d0becf9/jdk-8/Dockerfile) which puts mvn in `/usr/bin`.

You are not supposed to do a maven command, but rather, as [described in the doc](https://github.com/carlossg/docker-maven/tree/993474f006a59f487ef795864fab6115f9b1b8b5#create-a-dockerfile-in-your-maven-project)

```
FROM maven:3.2-jdk-7-onbuild
CMD ["do-something-with-built-packages"]
```

> Put this file in the root of your project, next to the `pom.xml`.
>
> This image includes multiple ONBUILD triggers which should be all you need to bootstrap. The build will `COPY . /usr/src/app` and RUN `mvn install`.

That means the resulting image has already copied the sources and mvn compiled the application, because of the `ONBUILD` directive, making it a poor candidate for Dockerhub Automated builds.

Comment: I am little confused on what you are saying. My needs are to run the application. What do I need to do to make it happen? In the local environment I am using the different mvn plugins to get a clean startup. How can I achieve it in Docker? Should I or should I not use the ONBUILD image? Or should I write ONBUILD triggers of my own. I know this is a bit basic, but all the same I am struggling with it.

Comment: @Ritwik I mean the application is already compiled on docker build. That is what the base image does with its ONBUILD directive. So your image should have as CMD a command which runs the application, not compiling it.

Comment: maybe I need a little hand-holding here. So I have modified the Dockerfile and it now looks like this: `FROM maven:3.3-jdk-7-onbuild

CMD ["mvn jetty:run"]` When I do a docker run, it still throws me a similar error `docker: Error response from daemon: Container command 'mvn jetty:run' not found or does not exist..`